# Solr Millions of search queries at once

Tags: java, batch-file, solr, bulk, pairing

I have to do pairing between reference addresses (about 30 millions in a PostGreSQL database) and files containing other addresses (many files a month, each file containing millions of adresses.

I already managed to import reference addresses in SolR and the search engine is great. Is there a way I can create a handler or plugin that would do the pairing for each row of the file very very fast?

I can't use the REST API doing millions of http request on SolR, that would be too slow. I just want to get the result as "id pairing", for example if ID 17 address of the file "somefile.csv" matches IDS 36, 452, and 13456 of reference addresses, that's all I need to retrieve, I can ask the database about more information later on.

I'd like to do it in Java but any other language is possible too.

Comment: That close as duplicate is not valid. This question has a proper answer, and the question it was closed as a duplicate of is not really relevant to how you could solve the asked question in Solr today.

Comment: Ask the question again Julien and I'll provide you with a possible solution using streaming expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create two collections - one you already have, containing the address you want to match against. The second collection should contain the contents of the CSV file you want to use for looking up adresses - you can [upload the CSV file directly as documents](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVFormattedIndexUpdates) in Solr.

After having set up the two collections and their corresponding files, use the [Streaming Expressions support](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html) in Solr to write a `leftOuterJoin` (or a different join if you want another behavior) between the two collections. That way you'll get all the entries from your uploaded file back, enriched with the original id of the matching address' id.

Given the two collections `addresses` (containing original adresses) and `uploaded_file` (containing the uploaded CSV rows), a join expression can be written as:

```
leftOuterJoin(
  search(uploaded_file, q=*:*, fl="id,address", sort="address asc"),
  select(
    search(addresses, q=*:*, fl="id,address", sort="address asc"),
    address AS original_address,
    id AS original_id
  ),
  on="address=original_address"
)
```

Using the "Stream" section on the Admin page for your collection will allow you to experiment with expressions.

Using the following test documents and collections, the result is as follows:

Documents in `addresses`:

```
  {
    "id":"add1",
    "address":"foo st. 33",
    "_version_":1606950875589246976},
  {
    "id":"add2",
    "address":"foo st. 49",
    "_version_":1606950875591344128},
  {
    "id":"add3",
    "address":"bar lane 1",
    "_version_":1606950875591344129},
  {
    "id":"add1-duplicate",
    "address":"foo st. 33",
    "_version_":1606951820879462400}
```

Documents in `uploaded_file`:

```
  {
    "id":"up1",
    "address":"foo st. 33",
    "_version_":1606950921604956160},
  {
    "id":"up2",
    "address":"foo st. 72",
    "_version_":1606950921607053312},
  {
    "id":"up3",
    "address":"bar lane 1",
    "_version_":1606950921607053313}
```

Running the expression gives us:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "original_address": "bar lane 1",
    "address": "bar lane 1",
    "id": "up3",
    "original_id": "add3"
  },
  {
    "original_address": "foo st. 33",
    "address": "foo st. 33",
    "id": "up1",
    "original_id": "add1"
  },
  {
    "original_address": "foo st. 33",
    "address": "foo st. 33",
    "id": "up1",
    "original_id": "add1-duplicate"
  },
  {
    "address": "foo st. 72",
    "id": "up2"
  },
  {
    "EOF": true,
    "RESPONSE_TIME": 28
  }
]
```

This gives you both addresses matching the one document uploaded, as well as those that doesn't match anything (where `original_id` is missing).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, I would never have guessed this could work. I'm gonna try this, it looks very simple and I already know how to create cores.

Comment: Almost worked, but I get this message : {
  "result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "EXCEPTION":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A HostProvider may not be empty!",
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":2319}]}}

Comment: I'm wondering if this is not made to work only with collections?

Comment: It does require you to run Solr in cloud mode, yes. But that can be a single node as well.

Comment: Oh that's great, Thank you

Comment: Like you said, some addresses will have a perfect match, some others won't. Is there a way I can use another stream expression for others giving unperfect matches? Or is it possible by developing a request handler for example?

Comment: Then you'll have to decide what an "unperfect match" is first; what kind of error would you consider being "within reason"? You're getting close to having to invoke a complete search for each term instead. You could possibly index a "normalized" value and use that for testing similarity instead, maybe as two separate lists.

Comment: Perfect, your first suggestion is what I was thinking about, hoping that perfect matches would be very numerous and other very few, so I could cluster them, do a search for each unperfect match cluster and post-analysis the result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Last question and I'll stop bothering, is it possible to perform multiple query with only one http request? Or just a "few". For example, let's say I have 2 millions adresses out of ten, that don't have perfect match, can I group them by city code and street name, reducing it to 1,5 million, and then perform 1,5 search query at once with SolR? Or do I have to look at another Lucene base solution?

Comment: Make a separate query to retrieve those that doesn't match (by attaching an additional filter after the join in my example), then query those using either separate queries or a larger set of boolean queries (default limit: 1000 terms) depending on how you want to retrieve your matches. Using multiple terms may make it hard to determine exactly which addresses resulted in a hit or not.